# Простой способ сравнить дату с текущей и подправить нужным образом

Tags: java, строки, дата, форматирование, java-7

У меня строка типа такой `22.09.79`. Я хочу изменить ее на такую: `22.09.2079`, преобразовать в дату и сравнить текущей датой. Если текущая дата меньше, то в результате получить `22.09.1979`, в противном случае оставить `22.09.2079`. Как я могу это сделать максимально без костылей с `Java 7` ?

Comment: Пример Вашего кода, попыток. С чем нам работать? Не писать же код с нуля...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
 Date date = format.parse("22.09.79"); // тут вы получите 22.09.1979
 date = format.parse("22.09.12"); // тут вы получите 22.09.2012
```